# Create Tanuki Scripts With Gradle

Tags: gradle, java-service-wrapper

I am migrating from Maven to Gradle. However, I am stuck on the generation of Tanuki (Java Service Wrapper) scripts.

Maven has a [plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-jsw.html) in for this however, I can't see how to create the scripts with gradle.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that gradle has its plugin as well. It's called grapper and can be found [here](https://github.com/imrichardcole/grapper).

BTW: Unfortunately there's no possibility of using mavens plugin in gradle directly.

Comment: It isn't in maven central though

Comment: I can be found in oss snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/uk/co/imrichardcole/grapper/

Comment: @opticyclic, does my answer solve the problem? If so please accept it.

Comment: Don't be so needy! As mentioned, I can't use it because it isn't in Maven Central. I have opened a ticket with the author though https://github.com/imrichardcole/grapper/issues/1

Comment: I'm not needy. I just do not like leaving things unfinished. I've spent some time finding answer to your question (to be precise: it wasn't about plugin available via maven central, but about a plugin itself) and I wasn't even informed if it was correct/helpful or not :/ You don't need maven central to make it work. You can use it as a local jar dependency unless it's published.